# How to click a pagination page number in python using Selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've been struggling to figure out how to click on a page number of a pagination class for a couple of days now. I've tried a bunch of methods but I can only get as far as highlighting the container of the number, not actually clicking it.
[image: What it looks like when I click on the page number]

This is the source code for the pagination in the website:

```
<nav aria-label="pagination">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item false" data-page-number="<-">
            <a class="page-link" id="page-link«" href="#">«</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item active" data-page-number="1">
            <a class="page-link" id="page-link1" href="#">1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item " data-page-number="2">
            <a class="page-link" id="page-link2" href="#">2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item " data-page-number="3">
            <a class="page-link" id="page-link3" href="#">3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item " data-page-number="4">
            <a class="page-link" id="page-link4" href="#">4</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item " data-page-number="5">
            <a class="page-link" id="page-link5" href="#">5</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item false" data-page-number="->">
            <a class="page-link" id="page-link»" href="#">»</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This is my current code that I use to locate and click the page numbers:

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.pagination")))
    next_page_number = page_number + 1
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="page-link{next_page_number}"]').click()
    time.sleep(2)

except NoSuchElementException or TimeoutException:
    break
```

I've also tried to replace the .click() with a different method of executing using `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", page)`, but it didn't work any better.

`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//a[@href='#'][text()='{next_page_number}']").click()` - no different.

`driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.pagination").find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, f"{next_page_number}").click()` - ;-;

I've tried finding the number using css selector as well but that didn't help either. I've also tried instead of `click()`, using `send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`.

Overall I'm very lost, so any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The specific website I'm looking at is https://www.xior-booking.com

Comment: A link to the page is probably going to be necessary here. Something weird is going on and we're likely not going to be able to help without it. Have you tried something simple like hardcoding the ID, e.g. `driver.find_element(By.ID, 'page-link2').click()`?

Comment: @JeffC I added the link to the original post, and I tried your suggestion of hardcoding the ID but it unfortunately did not solve the issue.

Comment: They have bot protection on the site. It doesn't load 80% of the page when you run the script using Selenium and if you try to get around it, it does a verify human check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the nextpage locator you want to click as below to target with link element a

```
//li[@data-page-number="{next_page_number}"]//a
```

Then using a javscript click instead to click on the link

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", nextPageLink)
```

Full Code

```
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    import undetected_chromedriver as uc

    driver = uc.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://www.xior-booking.com/#')

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.pagination")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//li[@class="page-item '
                                                                                'active"]//a')))
    # first we get the current Active page number
    currentPageNumber = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//li[@class="page-item active"]//a').text
    # Then we calculate the next page number
    next_page_number = int(currentPageNumber) + 1
    nextPageLink = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//li[@data-page-number="{next_page_number}"]//a')

    # doing a javascript click instead fo element.click
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", nextPageLink)
    # Increased wait here to visually verify
    time.sleep(20)

except NoSuchElementException or TimeoutException:
    print("exception Occurred")
```

Clicked on page number 2 link
[image]

Comment: Chaudhay  - It would be good if you explain your answer or explain what changes you are suggesting.

Comment: This solution does seem to work, though, it seems the problem I had was more with setting up my chromeDriver options than how I clicked the button. When I switched to undetected_chromedriver, it started working as intented. Thank you for your help!